# Returning column with @ManytoMany relationship in NestJS TypeORM

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I am new in `NESTJS` and building a schema using `NestJS` and `TypeORM`and I have built my Entity like this:

```
import { Entity, Column, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, UpdateDateColumn, CreateDateColumn, DeleteDateColumn, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, ManyToMany, JoinTable, OneToOne } from "typeorm";
import { SportsCategory } from "../SportsCategories/sports-category.entity";
import { SportsFacility } from "../SportsFacilities/sports-facility.entity";
@Entity()
export class MyEntity {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number;

    @ManyToOne(() => SportsFacility, sportsFacility => sportsFacility.myEntity)
    sportsFacility: SportsFacility;

    @ManyToMany(() => SportsCategory)
    @JoinTable({ name: 'myEntity_sports_categories', joinColumn: { name: 'myEntity_id' }, inverseJoinColumn: { name: 'sports_category_id' }})
    sportsCategories: SportsCategory[];

   }
```

Now when I make a `get` call I do not get `sportsCategories` in the returned data.
I have tried using `eager: true` but I also heard its not efficient for heavier data.

Is there anything wrong in my code or am i missing something?